# The number of scalar multiplications needed to compute the n'th power of an nxn matrix

Tags: algorithm

How can I compute the `n`th power of an `n`×`n` matrix using at
 most `2log_2(n) * n^3` scalar multiplications?

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: I guess it's 2log_2(n) * n^3, which is a loose bound that covers exponentiation by squaring using naive matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naive matrix multiplication of two `n`x`n` matrices takes `n^3` scalar multiplications. That's because each entry in the result is the dot product of a row of the first matrix with a column of the second, both of which are of length `n`.

[Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) needs `floor(log_2(n))` squarings, and at most `floor(log_2(n))` multiplications (see the linked wikipedia page for details).

Thus, computing the `n`'th power of an `n`x`n` matrix by exponentiation by squaring and multiplication by naive matrix multiplication requires at most `n^3 * 2 log_2(n)` scalar multiplications.